# Webpack alias for strapi api

Tags: webpack, strapi, webpack-5

I'm new to working with Strapi 4. I have a folder 'src/services' which I would like to give an webpack alias.

There's a 'webpack.config.js' file under the 'src/admin' directory, but it seems to be exclusively for the admin part. How to create an alias for the API part?

Comment: Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I bumped in the exact same problem today and here is how I fixed this. For exemple with a utils directory :

1st add module-alias package

than in your package.json add

```
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@utils" : "dist/src/utils"
  },
```

than you need to modify the strapi script to use your aliase. For this open
node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js

And at the top add

```
require('module-alias/register')
```

To have this modification automatically restored after an install I use patch-packageI bumped in the exact same problem today and here is how I fixed this. For exemple with a utils directory :

1st add module-alias package

than in your package.json add

```
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@utils" : "dist/src/utils"
  },
```

than you need to modify the strapi script to use your aliase. For this open
node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js

And at the top add

```
require('module-alias/register')
```

To have this modification automatically restored after an install I use patch-package

Comment: You can also do the `require('module-alias/register')` in the index.js/index.ts file in the src directory of your strapi project. That way you don't have to modify the npm package in a sketchy way.